# How to customize default email notification template of project server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

I have MS Project server 2013 which is integrated with MS SharePoint 2013

I have enabled email notifications, when assigning task to resources

the default email notification is something like blow:

```
Project: BMW Project

Below are the latest schedule changes. Contact your project manager if there are any problems with the changes.

You have been assigned to the following assignments.

 Task Name: Setting Bag

 Start: Sunday, May 10, 2015  Finish: Wednesday, May 13, 2015  Work: 32h  Remaining Work: 32h  % Completion: 0

To turn off these notifications, go to PWA Settings, and then click Manage My Alerts and Reminders.

From this page, you can clear the check box for those notifications you no longer want to receive.

Microsoft Project Server
```

how can I customize this email template?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint there's a file named  alerttemplates.xml that holds all allert templates data in SharePoint.
You just need to change the part of the file that responsible for your list.
For more info:
http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2012/05/16/how-to-customise-sharepoint-alert-email-template.aspx